# Apache interprets JavaScript script as text/html

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, ckeditor

My host's server interprets it as `text/html`. It should be `application/x-javascript`. I am having this issue just with the file `js/CKEditor/blah.js` but I do not have the problem with `CKEditor/blah.js`...

I already added this ilne to my .htcaccess:

```
AddType application/x-javascript .js
```

I have no idea how to get the application header to be correct with paths like `js/folder/script`...

Comment: No it should be application/javascript

Comment: Thanks, but it still didn't solved my problem...

Comment: Do any other .htaccess tweaks work, your host may not be running Apache or may have disabled the user of .htaccess files. Also note that you've misspelled ".htcaccess" in your question so check that its spelled correctly on your server.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
<Location /yourpathhere>
ForceType application/javascript
</Location>
```

That will force the type of your files in the specified directory.